# Using csv data file for reducing the length of the code gets error a.all() or a.any()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wrote the following code. for fast running and briefing, I write a `31*31` matrix in a `csv` file as we can see in `CovSN`. I wonder how should I do it for `xx` and `yy` to remove `for loop` and `f_list[]` in `def SN(Om, A, al, M):` to write something like:

```
def dL(Om, A, al, M):   
    q_sn = quad(ant, 0, za, args=(Om,  A, al))[0]      
    h = 5 * log10( (1+za) * q_sn)  
    fn = (mua - M - h)            
    return fn

def SN(Om, A, al, M):
     sn= np.dot(dL(Om, A, al, M), np.dot(cova, dL(Om, A, al, M))
     return sn
```

But Python gets error when I do these replacement

```
if (b != Inf and a != -Inf): alueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). >>>
```

the code is

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pandas as pd

xx=np.array([0.01,0.012,0.014,0.016,0.019,0.023,0.026,0.031,0.037,0.043,
            0.051,0.06,0.07,0.082,0.097,0.114,0.134,0.158,0.186,0.218,
            0.257,0.302,0.355,0.418,0.491,0.578,0.679,0.799,0.94,1.105,1.3])

yy=np.array([32.95388698,33.87900347,33.84214074,34.11856704,34.59344598,
            34.93902653,35.25209633,35.74850165,36.06978761,36.43457047,
            36.65111059,37.15801411,37.43017325,37.95661635,38.25325404,
            38.61286934,39.06785071,39.3414019,39.79214362,40.1565346,
            40.56495606,40.90528778,41.42141744,41.79092346,42.23146107,
            42.61704707,43.05273149,43.50415083,43.97257341,44.51408758,44.82186746])   

cov = pd.read_csv('covSN.csv', header=None)
cova = cov.as_matrix(columns=None)
CovSN = np.asmatrix(cova)

def ant(z, Om, A, al):
    return (Om * (1 + z)**3 + (1 - Om)*(A+(1+A)*(1+z)**al)**(0.5))**(-0.5)  

def dL(n, Om, A, al, M):   
    q_sn = quad(ant, 0, xx[n], args=(Om,  A, al))[0]      
    h = 5 * log10((299000/70) * (1+xx[n]) * q_sn)  
    fn = (yy[n] - M - h)            
    return fn

def SN(Om, A, al, M):
    f_list = []
    for i in range(31):     
            f_list.append(dL(i, Om, A, al, M))
    rdag = [f_list]    
    rmat = [[f] for f in f_list] 
    m1 = np.dot(rdag,CovSN)         
    m2 = np.dot(m1,rmat)            
    x2_SN = np.linalg.det(m2) * 0.000001
    return x2_SN

print(SN(0.25, 1, -0.9, 0.02))
```

Comment: Please provide a sample `csv` (two or 3 lines) and state exactly in which line the error occurs. Preferably post the stackdump.

Comment: @kabanus `csv` file is just a number. it can be every thing. doesn't matter. error is `if (b != Inf and a != -Inf): alueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>>`

Comment: that's fine I'm suggestion tips for improving the question so it would be easier to help you and increase the chance of getting an answer. Post the error in the question, not comments (see the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50060781/edit) button). Also - I do not see that line in your code at all.

Comment: @kabanus Yes exactly. I dont know what does it mean. And what is its relation to my code.

Comment: for that reason post the entire stack dump (so we see where the error is coming from). Good edit so far.